# Jquery validation don't hide the error message when value is valid

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I wrote a decimal validation method to validate the text in a texbox:

```
$.validator.addMethod("decimalCheck", function(value) {
            var v = new RegExp("^\d*[0-9](\.\d*[0-9])?$", "g");
            return v.test(value);
        }, "Error here");
```

The first time, I inputed "12,34" string to textbox and error message display.
The second time, I inputed "12" string to textbox. That is valid string but error message doesn't hide.

Please help me resolving
thanks & best regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one (also slightly optimized regex with same functionality)

```
$.validator.addMethod("decimalCheck", function(value) {
    var v = /^\d+(\.\d+)?$/;
    return v.test(value);
}, "Error here");
```

---

Your problem is that you need to escape the backslash it self (double escape) else the regex constructor in reality get this string passed in (`"^d*[0-9](.d*[0-9])?$"`)

```
var v = new RegExp("^\\d*[0-9](\\.\\d*[0-9])?$", "g");
```

btw. using the `g` flag here could lead to unexpected results. Better leave it away as you are using `^` and `$` anyway.